# UWP - How Can Dispatcher DispatchedHandler Run On Worker Thread?

Tags: xaml, uwp

Im trying to update some UWP UI from a background thread via the Dispatcher.
However, the handler passwed to the RunAsync method is still getting executed on a backlground thread.

I have no idea how to fix this - have I missed something?

[image]

**--EDIT--**

I only have one window, which is `Window.Current`

I have tried the Community Toolkit DispatcherHelper class, but I'm still getting the **exact same exception**

```
private static async void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var panel = (SidePanelInfo) d;
    var x = e.NewValue as TaskItemViewModel;
    await DispatcherHelper.ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync(() =>
    {
        panel.DescriptionBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, x?.Description ?? "");
    });

}
```

Comment: have you tried setting the text without the dispatcher?

Comment: yup. I added the dispatcher call to try and fix because this looks like a cross-threading exception common to all XAML controls

Comment: ive looked at the live visual tree and there definitely is only 1 window. Im gonna delve into this more deeply myself now that I know that there isnt a straightforward answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: oK - this is unexpected. I've worked all the way back to the constructor in App.xaml.cs and its being called from a background thread. Thats most unexpected. All Windows, pages and controls are then loaded on a background thread. The SelectedItem is set during initialisation - all of which happens on a background thread. I really dont understand

Comment: Actually, this happens on every UWP app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have finally found out what was going on, and it was not what I was expecting.

The issue had nothing to do with threading or dispatchers, despite the dispatcher executing on a worker thread (UWP dispatchers dont seem to run on the Main Thread like WPF it seems), and despite the error being the same error as you would expect if you had a cross-threading UI exception.

It turns out that I had a RichEditBox that was inadvertently in read-only mode. And because this control doesn't support binding to its content, I was setting the content in code-behind. The exception was because I was setting the text of the control while it was in read-only mode.

It's a shame that the control couldn't have given a more meaningful error, or been editable programmatically even if in read-only mode - like the WPF equivalent. But there you go. Hopfully this Q&A page will help someone else having the same problems.

A big thanks to Martin Zikmund for attempting to help me when I was sure it was a dispatching issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are already on the background thread, you cannot access `Window.Current.Dispatcher` as the background thread has no `Window.Current` set (the property gets the `Window` instance associated with the UI thread it is called from).

Instead you should first retrieve the `Dispatcher` instance while on the UI thread and then use this instance to execute `RunAsync`.

However - `OnSelectedItemChanged` rather seems like a UI event handler in which case you should not require running code on UI thread. Check if the `UnauthorizedAccessException` does not happen if you just run `panel.DescriptionBox.Document.SetText` with the same parameters when triggered from a `Button` click for example.

### Multi-view and multi-window apps

The problem can occur in case you are creating a multi-view or multi-window UWP app, because in UWP each window has its own UI thread. This means that when you want to update properties across windows, you always need to use the `Dispatcher` of the target window/app view.

Comment: Its not possible to do that as this is a dependency property propertychangedcallback thats already on the background thread

Comment: You shouldn't modify dependency properties on non-UI thread in the first place - it would be better to instead use dispatcher when setting the dependency property itself.

Comment: I dont understand how the dependency callback is running on a background thread in the first place

Comment: Where are you setting the `SelectedItem`?

Comment: Aren't you creating multiple views (windows) of the app by any chance?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I assumed that (like WPF) you didnt have to marshall property changed to the UI thread in ViewModel bindings, and that the dependency system in UWP is like WPF where it ONLY works on the UI thread. Ill take a look at where Im setting up my ViewModel and marshall it there - thanks

Comment: In case you are creating multiple views in your app, each view has its own UI thread. So if you want to modify dependency properties cross-views, you always have to use the dispatcher of the target view. WPF on the other hand uses just a single UI thread across all windows

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect multi-view apps

Comment: only 1 window, dispatcher helper from the toolkit doesnt help - see edits. Thanks for any additional ideas

Comment: What calls the SelectedItemChanged method? A control or user action?

Comment: Its called from a dependency property a few lines above those described inside the same usercontrol. The DependencyProperty is bound to the SelectedItem on a ListView in the parent usercontrol. Its not called directly from code

Comment: Could you please add any additional code related to this process? There must be a reason for this 

Comment: As commented above, UWP apps initialise on a background thread, and remain on a background thread while initialising UI. The SelectedItem is set during Initialisation

Comment: Can you try using `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync()`?

Comment: Martin - have found the issue, nothing to do with threading (see my answer). Thanks for your help, and sorry if it wasted your time

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty interesting finding :-D. I would have never guessed this could be the issue. But glad you managed to solve it :-). Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

[DispatcherHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/dispatcherhelper) from the **WindowsCommunityToolkit** can be very helpful here.

it gives you option to execute code on UI thread or execute code on MainView ( if you have multiple windows )

```
DispatcherHelper.ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync<T>(() =>
{
    // Code to execute on main window's UI thread
});

await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.AwaitableRunAsync<T>( () =>
{

});
```