# UWP App crashes when Clipboard.GetContent() is called from inside OnNavigatedTo()

Tags: .net, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In a UWP App, when I try to retrieve the contents of the clipboard from within the `OnNavigatedTo` method, the app crashes. Could someone help on this please?

Edit: It seems to crash only when it is launched by clicking on it from the start menu or by launching it by an another app. But when launched by Visual Studio, it works fine!

Comment: I'm guessing you're doing this on the initial navigation, before your app gets focus. Only the focus app can access the clipboard.

Comment: Well, and what do you suggest as a solution? i.e. can I set my app somehow programmatically in focus?

Comment: Wait until your app gets focus, and get the clipboard at that time. Or even better: Wait for the user to perform an action that indicates that they want your app to retrieve information from the clipboard. Apps that spontaneously read the clipboard are generally looked upon as suspicious (information-stealing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugging in visual studio is different from the start menu, you can try the Resuming and Suspending event when you run the app in vs, these event won't be triggered normally.

In addition, about the Clipboard, this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard#remarks) mentions you need to use Clipboard after CoreWindow is active. When the OnNavigatedTo event is triggered, the CoreWindow is not ready yet. You could try the following code and the Activated event will triggered many times, you can add some judgments in it.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    CoreWindow window = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread();
    window.Activated += Window_Activated; 

}

private async void Window_Activated(CoreWindow sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
    var text = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem if you use `Clipboard` in `OnNavigatedTo` or even earlier (like in page constructor), but you **must** call `Clipboard` APIs from the UI thread. Meaning the following will work:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var content = Clipboard.GetContent();
}
```

But the following will crash:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    await Task.Run(() => { Clipboard.GetContent(); });
}
```

Please make sure, your code does indeed access the `Clipboard` from the UI thread and it should work properly. To move to the UI thread, you can use the `Dispatcher` (see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373127/uwp-how-can-dispatcher-dispatchedhandler-run-on-worker-thread/))

Comment: Actually, neither the first code nor the second one works!

Comment: That is super unusual. Could you create a simple sample project and put it on GitHub so I can test it locally?

Comment: I realized now that the problem occurs only when I call another app after retrieving data from the clipboard. I mean with a code like the following:
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
   bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-screensketch:edit"));
}
And it does not occure if the app is launched by Visual Stuido, but only when it is started by the user by clicking its name in the list of installed programs.

Comment: I am realizing now that it crashes even without calling other apps. Just try to launch it by clicking the name of the program in the start menu